# Update application version number after successful pull request

Tags: git, github, versioning, pull-request

I develop a web application using Visual Studio 2015 with git as source control. Is there a way to automatically update application version number with each successful GitHub pull request that merges a new feature back into Dev branch, and update it in a different way when merging from Dev to Main branch? I don't want to do it manually. Is there a known way to achieve such thing?

Comment: Please note that Git (the software) and online web services such as GitHub have different definitions of the term "pull request". See [How to send a pull request on GIT](//stackoverflow.com/a/6235394/2747593). It sounds like you are referring to the latter rather than the former. If that is the case, you should change the [tag:git] tag to [tag:github]. Also, what is the [tag:powershell] tag here for?

Comment: The powershell tag is here because I figured it would most probably be the solution, have some sort of script attached to each pull request which will automatically increase the version number

Comment: Are you looking for [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)?

Comment: @S.Peter: Okay. If you have a preference for PowerShell over e.g. Bash, then I'd recommend you note that in the body of your question. Otherwise the tag is probably not necessary.

Comment: Specifically, you may try to use `post-merge` hook.

Comment: I'm very new to using git, just switched from tfs.. can you give me some more information about those `post-merge` hooks? If I set those on the server repository can I make them run after a successful pull request to a specific branch? Is there a similiar example or a guide you recommend me to follow?

Comment: @S.Peter For completeness, please [edit] your post to clarify if you are referring GitHub pull requests rather than the `git request-pull` command.